# Proving the monotonicity of an expression.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Fix $a\geq 0$. I'd like to show that the function $f(x) = x\ln(1+\frac{a}{x})$ is nondecreasing.

Here is what I have:

$f'(x) = \ln(\frac{a+x}{x}) - \frac{a}{a+x} = \dfrac{(a+x)\ln(\frac{a+x}{x})-a}{a+x}$

$f''(x) = \frac{a}{(a+x)^2} -\frac{a}{(x+a)(x)}$

What am I missing? I see that $f'' \leq 0$, though I can't tell that $f'\geq 0$.  The information about the second derivative is not too useful since it says that the first derivative is decreasing, which won't guarantee its positivity.

Is there another way to show this? Or am I almost there?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$? (Yes, you're almost there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle f^{\prime}(x)=\ln\big(\frac{a+x}{x}\big)-\frac{a}{a+x}\;\;\;$

where  $\ln\big(\frac{a+x}{x}\big)=\ln(a+x)-\ln x=\frac{1}{c}\cdot a$ with $x<c<a+x$ by  the Mean Value Theorem.

Since $\frac{1}{c}>\frac{1}{a+x}$, $\;\;\;\ln(a+x)-\ln x>\frac{a}{a+x}$ and therefore $f^{\prime}(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

This shows that f is increasing on $(0,\infty)$, and applying the Mean Value Theorem on $[-x-a,-x]$ with a similar argument shows that f is also increasing on $(-\infty,-a)$.

Comment: This is a nice application of the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Using the hint above due to Daniel Fischer with the help of L'Hopital's rule, $\lim f'(x) = \lim \dfrac{(a+x)\ln(\frac{a+x}{x})}{a+x} = \lim \ln(\frac{a+x}{x}) = 0$.

Thus $f'(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Since $f'(x)$ is a decreasing function - as $f'' \leq 0$, $\inf_{x \geq 0} f'(x) = 0$ and $f'$ is nonnegative, so that $f$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: You don't need L'Hopital. The argument of the logarithm, $1 + \frac{a}{x}$ tends to $1$ for $x\to \infty$, hence $\log \left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)\to 0$, and $\frac{a}{a+x} \to 0$ for $x\to \infty$ too. IMO, that's simpler than L'Hopital (YMMV).

Comment: Good point. Yes this is easier. Thanks!